# TCHAR Array to a concatenate LPCSTR

Tags: c++, visual-c++, tchar

I am reading a ini file and want to execute a external program (VBS File) after that. But I am having problems with the string types.

This is my code.

```
LPCTSTR path = _T(".\\my.ini");
TCHAR fileName[500];
int b = GetPrivateProfileString(_T("Paths"), _T("filename"), _T(""), fileName, 500, path);
// fileName = myscript.vbs
// I need to execute "wscript myscript.vbs arg1"
// Execute script file. Doesnt work.
WinExec("wscript " + fileName + " arg1", MINIMZIED);
// OR. Doesnt work.
system("wscript " + fileName + " arg1");
```

This doesnt work. WinExec wants a `LPCSTR` but I have the `fileName` in a `TCHAR[]` and want to concatenate with some other string.

How can I convert or concatenate it correctly?

Answer (score 2):

From the [WinExec() documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-winexec):

> This function is provided only for compatibility with 16-bit Windows. Applications should use the `CreateProcess` function.

Which is [`CreateProcessW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) in your case.

Alternatively, you can use `_wsystem()`.

Comment: And when you go with `CreateProcessW`, get rid of all the `TCHAR` stuff. Use wide characters throughout, not something that might be wide character and might not. 20 years ago it was a useful bridge as the world adjusted to Windows NT-based OSes, but when was the last time you needed to write code to support Windows 98?

Comment: I don´t need to support Windows 98. I think the minimum would be Windows Server 2000. I am new to C++ and I am still learing a lot. Can you provide a code snippet for my case?

Comment: Simply replace `T` with `W` in your string types, replace `_T()` with the `L` prefix, and append `W` to API function names, eg: `LPCWSTR path = L".\\my.ini"; WCHAR fileName[500]; int b = GetPrivateProfileStringW(L"Paths", L"filename", L"", fileName, 500, path); ...`

Answer (score 1):

You need to concatenate the strings using another buffer, for example:

```
LPCTSTR path = _T(".\\my.ini");
TCHAR fileName[500];
TCHAR command[520];

int b = GetPrivateProfileString(_T("Paths"), _T("filename"), _T(""), fileName, 500, path);
_stprintf_s(command, 520, _T("wscript %.*s arg1"), b, filename);
```

Then you can use `command` as needed, eg:

```
STARTUPINFO si = {};
si.cb = sizeof(si);
si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
si.wShowWindow = SW_MINIMIZED;

PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {};

if (CreateProcess(NULL, command, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
{
    ...
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
}
```

Or:

```
#ifdef UNICODE
#define system_t(cmd) _wsystem(cmd)
#else
#define system_t(cmd) system(cmd)
#endif

system_t(command);
```